# Test is file exists before opening in javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open, file-exists

Is it possible to check if a file exists with javascript, before opening it?

The user can fill in a product number in the form and after submitting, the datasheet will be downloaded, but it gives a 404 error when a product number is entered that doesn't exist.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="fastpdf()" action="#">

<input placeholder="article number" id="text" type="number">

<input type="submit" id="btn" value="&#8681;" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function fastpdf() {

    var pdfurl = '/download/products/' + document.getElementById('text').value + '.pdf'
         if (File.Exists(pdfurl))
     {
         window.open(pdfurl);
     }
     else{
         alert("This product does not have a datasheet!");
     }
    }
```

Comment: test with an ajax call to the file. if the status returns 404, the file does not exist

Comment: what is the implementation of `File.Exists`?

Comment: checking if a file exists in the server can only be done in the server... unless you do an XHR as suggested